# Install rust on wsl

Tags: curl, installation, rust

I have been trying to install Rust via `rustup` on a Windows Subsytem for Linux (wsl) as mentioned [here](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install).

`curl --proto '=https' --tlsv1.2 -sSf https://sh.rustup.rs | sh`

which keeps erring to

```
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

Some SO answers mention using `-k/--insecure` to get around this, so I executed `curl --insecure --proto ...` to no avail. Some issues on GitHub mention using `export RUST_USE_HYPER=1` pre `curl`ing but I didn't do that as I have no idea what that means (or if it works). I also tried downloading `rustup-init.sh` directly (from `https://sh.rustup.rs`) and then just running it but it also gives the same error. I haven't yet found a lead on some other way of being able to do this.

How does one install `rustup` in wsl?

**Env:**
Windows 10 ver 20H2
WSL ver 1

Comment: Are you on a network with some sort of proxy?  Do you have a non-default antivirus or firewall?  If the latter, does completely uninstalling it and restarting fix the problem?

Comment: @bk2204 no proxies just wifi ... whats a non-default antivirus? I do have an antivirus on windows....I m currently updating wsl to ver 2.  I have been able to apt-get upgrade before so there shouldn't be any network issues

Comment: Non-default means antivirus other than Windows Defender and firewall other than Windows Firewall.  Some of these programs actually intercept all your traffic to scan for malicious data.  Unfortunately, many times they don't work with WSL and actually make security worse.

Comment: thnx..yes its non-default...so you think the AV(anti-virus) is blocking `https://sh.rustup.rs`?... if so why does curl say `curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain` instead of the more sensible "unable to reach so and so"

Comment: @bk2204 your AV suspicion was spot on! My AV wasn't prompting me about its blocking of urls ..it started doing so post a system restart..I added to exclusions and curl worked as given! Thanks a ton for your time.... I'll gladly accept if you post ... there's no warning on the Rust website regarding this possible behaviour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message means that the certificate you're getting when you connect to sh.rustup.rs is self-signed.  Since the advent of free certificate authorities, almost nobody operates a website with a self-signed certificate because they are vulnerable to man-in-the-middle attacks.  sh.rustup.rs is no exception, so seeing a self-signed certificate means that someone is tampering with your connection.

In your case, that's a non-default antivirus.  Some antivirus programs try to scan all traffic into or out of the machine for viruses, and in order to intercept those connections, they insert a root certificate authority into the Windows system certificate store and use it to impersonate all your connections.

However, this doesn't work with WSL because it and the programs in it don't use the Windows certificate store.  As such, it sees this for what it is: an attack on your data.  Most antivirus programs that do this actually substantially weaken the security of the connection by choosing worse versions of TLS or worse ciphers or, in some cases, entirely neglecting to do proper certificate verification, leaving you exposed to MITM attacks by anyone on the Internet.  In any event, it will soon fail to work at all with the advent of encrypted SNI with TLS 1.3.

Therefore, the proper thing to do to fix this, and secure your computer, is to either entirely disable this feature in your antivirus and remove the rogue CA or completely uninstall the antivirus and use Windows Defender.  That will prevent your antivirus from intercepting this connection and allow programs in WSL to work.